# Using expressions for axis labels in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I would like to use an expression in the `LabelsFormat` field of a Values axis, thus not the Categories axis, in a Report Builder range chart.

That way I could do a calculation on the label value. 
However, it is not clear to me how I specify the value of the label in the expression.

The effective use case I am trying to achieve is to display a date (for example `2/1/2017`) as `Q1/16` (thus first quarter of 2017)

I can then use something like:

```
="Q" + Month(???)/4 + "/" + Year(????)
```

This all would result in a range chart something like:

[image]

and thus the question is: what do I use for the question marks?

EDIT: Unfortunately the number of quarters is not fixed, so the answer of @iamdave below will not work for me.

Thanks,

Serge

Answer (score 0):

Value Labels cannot be edited in the way that you want them to be.  The only way you could make this report work as you would like would be:

- Firstly make sure your chart is always a known number of quarters.
- Remove the horizontal axis.
- Create a table that sits directly underneath the chart, with a column group that generates the known number of quarters and formats the value accordingly.
- Make the top of the table look like the axis.

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm not trying to do this on the Categories Group, but instead on the Values axis, I've updated the question to reflect this

Comment: @SergeDesmedt  You have dates as your Y axis?  How does that work...?  Can you add a snippet of your chart design to your question please?

Comment: I'm following [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3521/sql-server-reporting-services-range-charts/) tutorial, see the section on Gantt charts. As in the example I have dates (which are actually _number of days_ ) and then set axis properties to show them as dates

Comment: @SergeDesmedt  The date is in the Category Group in that tutorial.

Comment: No, the Tasks are in the Categories Group

Comment: @SergeDesmedt Ah that with your edit makes more sense.  I have edited your question to state Range chart rather than Bar.  It is important that you take the time to include these details in your original question.  Screenshots of what you are doing is also very helpful.

Comment: @SergeDesmedt  I have edited my answer to give you the only option I can think of in your situation, which I have successfully used in the past.

Comment: Unortunately, the number of quarters is not fixed, I'e updated my question

Comment: @SergeDesmedt  Then what you want to do is not possible.  You could have `Jan 2017  |  Apr 2017  |  Jul 2017  |  Oct 2017` by using a month interval of 3 but that is about it.